# React Native App Customization using Express JS Back-end?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

I wonder is this a way to operate for an app design (Let say colors, or logo) customization. I had setup an admin panel for an React Native E-Commerce app, and if I want to customize the app, maybe header color or company logo etc, from time to time, what is the correct way to do so? Should I store those customization data (colors code etc) in DB and read it every time when the app is launched at the back end? Or?

Comment: look for server side rendering in react officail website

Comment: I think the simple solution is to store application customization data on the database and read before application starts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want it to be. If you want the user's customization to be saved and can be restored from different device, then you have to store it on database, and get the customization data every time when the app is launched.

Another alternative way is to store it on client side storage (like `localStorage`), this is useful  if you want to store a not really important customization settings for example, theme, app language, etc. Since this is stored on client side storage, if the user's changed their device or clean their local storage the customization will get reseted. I find this options to be useful especially for a non crucial data since it reduce the overhead of sending HTTP request to backend server, storing and retrieving the customization data from database.

Comment: Alright. I think I will just go for the database option. Thanks for the information thou.